# Image is displaying with the url of the image as well

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

[image]

**So its displaying the image like i want it, but the url of image comes with it as well.** Here is the code that i'm using.

[image]

Comment: ACF and other third party plugins are out of scope for this site, sorry. Taking another look at your code: You do have `img_block_left` twice in there - one call will directly output, the other will return.

Comment: In the image you the the following, `<?php the_field('img_block_left'); ?>`. In general `the_` outputs data, `get_` returns data, so the reason you see this is because of that function.